# Test if text in a range of cells exists on a single cell

Tags: google-sheets

In **Sheet 1** I have a list of emails and I would like to add a status (either **Good** or **Bad** / **true** or **false**) next to it if the email contains any of the substrings in the **Sheet 2**.

**Sheet 2** has a list of substrings that constitute a "bad email" such as `@test.com` or `noreply` that are in a list of cells.

Here is the desired output
[image]

I've searched around and cannot find similar questions so I think this would be helpful for those searching for the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textjoin()` to build a [regular expression](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754) and use it to test the email addresses, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  ifs( 
    isblank(A2:A), iferror(1/0), 
    regexmatch( A2:A, textjoin("|", true, Bad!B2:B) ), "Bad", 
    true, "Good" 
  ) 
)
```

To learn the exact regular expression syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: Thanks a ton! Really. Never would have been able to figure this out on my own